# Redux/React. Cannot get store.getState in nested components via Provider

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So, I try to understand how the data flow work in React/Redux, but I cannot figure out how to get the `store.getState()` in the nested components of the app, for example in the main `App` component. I push it via `Provider`, but...

What is I'm doing wrong?

/* INDEX.JS */

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import TodoApp from './Reducers/TodoApp'
import App from './Components/App';
import './Styles/style.css';

const store = createStore(TodoApp);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

/* NESTED COMPONENT */

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import VisibleTodoList from '../Containers/VisibleTodoList';
import TodoFormAdd from '../Containers/TodoFormAdd';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.store.getState()); // this is not work - "undefined", why?
        return(
            <Fragment>
                <TodoFormAdd />
                <VisibleTodoList  />
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I would suggest reading `redux/react-redux` tutorials, especially about _reducers, actions & `connect`_. It doesnt work in a way as you described

Comment: Thanks. I did it, but have a lot of white spots. That's why I' writing here to understand Redux closer. @TheReason

Comment: you are passing it to provider no the <App />. You basically have to use redux connect for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping the *Provider* component from react-redux around your app is only one of two modification you have to make to your code to make Redux work.

The components need to “wired up” with the redux state, using [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options).

Take a look at the [“official” example from the react-redux documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todomvc/src/containers/App.js).

In your case, this would look something like this:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import VisibleTodoList from '../Containers/VisibleTodoList';
import TodoFormAdd from '../Containers/TodoFormAdd';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        // displays the todos from the global redux stpre
        console.log(this.props.todos);
        return(
            <Fragment>
                <TodoFormAdd />
                <VisibleTodoList  />
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

// pick the parts of the Redux state that you want
// to use as props in your connected component
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    todos: state.todos
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score -2):

console.log(this.props.store.getState()); // this is not work - "undefined", why?

This is because 'store' is not a prop of class App

If you want to get store as a prop in App

try modifying your code to

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App store={store}/>
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Pushing the store throw the App component is not the React-Redux pattern way to do it. Must be the natural way of Redux to make it.

Comment: console.log(this.props.store.getState()); , How can App get store as props unless you dont pass as a prop